# Formato de fecha en eloquent -laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent, carbon

Usando laravel 8 y mysql, tengo que hacer una consulta para sacar el Año de mi bd.

pero no logro convertir ese dato de mi bd, a un formato tipo carbon para poder convertir solo el año.

si yo ejecuto la consulta normal, esta funciona:

```
$anio = InitialData::select('fecha_sol')->orderby('fecha_sol', 'asc')->distinct()->get();
```

en mi bd, tengo los datos guardados de esta forma:  **2021-05-11T00:00:00**

y en mi consulta quisiera poder traer solo el año.

```
$anio = InitialData::select('fecha_sol')->orderby('fecha_sol', 'asc')->format('Y')->distinct()->get();
```

pero me marca error, de format().
Encontré que tendria que convertirla primero a carbon, pero no se como funciona esta manera de convertir a carbon.

```
Carbon::parse //

$anio = InitialData::select(Carbon::parse('fecha_sol')->format('Y'))->orderby('fecha_sol', 'asc')->distinct()->get();
```

alguien podria indicarme como usarlo? muchas gracias.

Comment: No veo la necesidad de usar carbon, lo puedes hacer desde la propia consulta, algo asi: `selectRaw('YEAR(fecha_sol) as fecha_sol')`

Comment: Muchas gracias, es justo lo que necesitaba!.

Comment: A la inversa como seria? si tengo el año 2021, como podria consultar ese campo? los del año 2021? o un mes o un dia? gracias.

Comment: MySQL tiene funciones de fecha, `YEAR` es una de ellas, te sugiera investigar o formular una nueva pregunta, pero en resumen utilizarias `MONTH` o `DAY`